# How can i get automatically property names from array with rest operator?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object.

```
let userInput = {
    "id": "22a52279-cc48-430e-ada6-88a3f67cbb8b",
    "first_name": "test",
    "email": "test@hotmail.com",
    "created_at": "2021-04-06T18:19:01.567Z",
    "salary": null,
    "department_name": null,
    "department_id": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "gender": null,
    "updated_at": "2021-04-06T18:19:01.567Z",
    "address": "ad12",
    "phone": null,
    "city": null,
    "university_name": null,
    "university_city": null,
    "about": null,
    "is_admin": null
}
```

if i want to get some properties from this object and use them in another object i will do:

```
 const {first_name, address, phone, city, university_name, university_city, about} = this.userInput;
    this.user = {first_name, address, phone, city, university_name, university_city, about};
    console.log(this.user);
```

then i get in the `user` variable this output

```
{
    "first_name": "test",
    "address": "ad12",
    "phone": null,
    "city": null,
    "university_name": null,
    "university_city": null,
    "about": null
}
```

to prevent repeating my self - i wanted to store all this needed proeprty names in one array and reuse it so i tried

```
const getNeededProperties = ["first_name", " address", " phone", " city", " university_name", " university_city", " about"];
const {first_name, address, phone, city, university_name, university_city, about} = this.userInput;
this.user = {...getNeededProperties};
```

i will get the same output - so basically i store `first_name` then `address` etc...  as local variables
and then i am assaigning them to the user object - i destructure the property names and it is working

but when i try to rest the property names from the array

```
 const getNeededProperties = ["first_name", " address", " phone", " city", " university_name", " university_city", " about"];
      const {...getNeededProperties} = this.userInput;
      this.user = {...getNeededProperties};
```

i get error

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'getNeededProperties'.

Is there some way that i con all of this automatically ?

Comment: seems your destructuring just to destructure, why not make a `Object.getProperties(["first_name"])` function and pass it what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this:

```js
const userInput = {
    "id": "22a52279-cc48-430e-ada6-88a3f67cbb8b",
    "first_name": "test",
    "email": "test@hotmail.com",
    "created_at": "2021-04-06T18:19:01.567Z",
};
const neededProps = ["id", "first_name"];

const user = neededProps.reduce((res, prop) => ({
    ...res, [prop]: userInput[prop]
  }), {});
  
console.log(user);
```

Comment: That's the solution that I was about to suggest too. However, I would additionally check inside reduce function, if given property exists on the object.

Comment: I think that depends on the use case. Generally, I like seeing clearly that the property has a value of `undefined` when I expected it, rather than not seeing the property at all

Comment: @blex TNX FOR THE REPLY

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following utility to copy fields from one object to another.

```js
const fieldsToCopy = ['first_name', 'address', 'phone', 'city', 'university_name', 'university_city', 'about'];
this.user = copyFields(this.userInput, fieldsToCopy);
```

copyFields.js

```js
function copyFields (originalObject, fieldsToCopy) {
  const newObject = {};

  for (const key in originalObject) {
    if (fieldsToCopy.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
      newObject[key] = originalObject[key];
    }
  }

  return newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const foo = {
  "first_name": "test",
  "address": "ad12",
  "phone": null,
  "city": null,
  "university_name": null,
  "university_city": null,
  "about": null
}
const arr = ["first_name", "address", "phone"]

// 1
const user = arr.reduce((a, p) => (a[p] = foo[p], a), {})
// 2
const user2 = Object.fromEntries(arr.map((p) => [p, foo[p]]))

console.log(user)
console.log(user2)
```